# what is the use of org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In my project all the manager classes implemented like this pattern,

```
<bean id="companyManagerTxProxy" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="proxyTargetClass"><value>true</value></property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
             <props>
                <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="companyAdminManager" parent="companyManagerTxProxy" scope="prototype">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="lucky.src.bto.controllerImpl.CompanyAdminManagerImpl">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

can you please explain me why we are using org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean in creating all the manager's beans. what is the exactly use of it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a broad question because there are conceptual explanation to be done here. In very short: TransactionProxyFactoryBean is part of Spring's Transaction support and allows applications to have a "transactional" behavior in server-independent way. In other words: You may replace EJB Container Managed beans if you configure your services using TransactionProxyFactoryBean.

[Please refer to Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionProxyFactoryBean.html)

You may need to understand the concept of Transaction overall. But a very short explanation is:

> Transactions (read or write of information) must be [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and
>   ensure that we need to give "transactional" behavior the software
>   resources (code) which interact with the database (there may be other
>   transactions).

The above explanation touches a bit on AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) where in, the behavior you want to give with the transactions is "aspect".

There are usually three things that need to be configured:

> transactionManager, target and transactionAttribute.

The transactionAttribute is where you give transactional behavior for the read and writes for your resources. In your example, your `companyAdminManager` is given trnasactional behavior. The `companyAdminManager` in turn must be configured with `datasource` which would have db url, user/pass and other pertinent information.

> Here are two good explanations (explains each and every line)
>
> 1.) [Click this to to read each line of configuration explained](https://nerdnotes.wordpress.com/2007/03/30/basic-transactions-in-spring-using-transactionproxyfactorybean/)
>
> 2.) I find the following blog post by Scot to be basic and easy to understand example with explanation. Please read [click here](https://nofluffjuststuff.com//blog/scott_leberknight/2006/01/declaring_transaction_attributes_on_spring_s_transactionproxyfactorybean)

Answer (score 0):

Spring **declarative** transactions can be IMPERATIVE(PlatformTransactionManager.class)  or REACTIVE (ReactiveTransactionManager.class). Under the hood both classes only differ in the TrasactionInterceptor, which is the AOP/AspectJ class that provides advice to transaction methods. You need to understand AOP/AspectJ to understand previous statement.

If you want to programmatically extend Spring transactions instead of implement a whole new TransactionManager you just need to supply the TransactionInterception.

For example:

```
 @Bean 
public TransactionInterceptor txAdvice() { 
  new TransactionInterceptor() {
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) {

    //......have some fun

     }
  };
}
```